# Unable to run a jspx page in Jdevloper.These error messeges is coming in my log

Tags: jdeveloper

*** Using port 7101 ***
C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jdbc_11.1.1\ojdbc6dms.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.5.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\wcps-lib\derby-10.6.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\wcps-lib\derbytools-10.6.1.0.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware11.1.1.6.0\jdeveloper\webcenter\modules\oracle.portlet.server_11.1.1\oracle-portlet-api.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware11.1.1.6.0\jdeveloper\webcenter\modules\wcps_11.1.1.4.0\wcps-connection-mbeans.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrf.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\x64;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files\Trend Micro\AMSP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8
.

---

- To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
- password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
- server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
- console at http:\hostname:port\console        *

  ---

starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_2\bin\java -client   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dweblogic.Name=DefaultServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks -Doracle.adfm.usemds=true -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true  -Xverify:none  -da -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\WLSERV~1.3\server  -Djps.app.credential.overwrite.allowed=true -Dcommon.components.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\ORACLE~1 -Djrf.version=11.1.1 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Ddomain.home=C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1 -Djrockit.optfile=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.jrf_11.1.1\jrocket_optfile.txt -Doracle.server.config.dir=C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\servers\DefaultServer -Doracle.domain.config.dir=C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1  -Digf.arisidbeans.carmlloc=C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\carml  -Digf.arisidstack.home=C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\FMWCON~1\arisidprovider -Doracle.security.jps.config=C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\config\fmwconfig\jps-config.xml -Doracle.deployed.app.dir=C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\servers\DefaultServer\tmp_WL_user -Doracle.deployed.app.ext=- -Dweblogic.alternateTypesDirectory=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.ossoiap_11.1.1,C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\ORACLE~1\modules\oracle.oamprovider_11.1.1 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=oracle.mds.net.protocol  -Dweblogic.jdbc.remoteEnabled=false -Dwsm.repository.path=C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDEVEL~1\SYSTEM~1.92\DEFAUL~1\oracle\store\gmds  -DUSE_JAAS=false -Djps.policystore.hybrid.mode=false -Djps.combiner.optimize.lazyeval=true -Djps.combiner.optimize=true -Djps.auth=ACC -Doracle.core.ojdl.logging.usercontextprovider=oracle.core.ojdl.logging.impl.UserContextImpl -noverify -Doracle.webcenter.analytics.disable-native-partitioning=false -Doracle.webcenter.tagging.scopeTags=false -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dportlet.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware11.1.1.6.0\jdeveloper -Dwc.oracle.home=C:\Oracle\Middleware11.1.1.6.0\jdeveloper  -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\patch_wls1035\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1.0\patch_jdev1111\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
<22 Nov, 2013 8:27:35 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:27:35 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:27:35 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:27:36 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:27:47 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:27:57 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:28:07 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:28:17 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:28:27 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:28:37 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:28:47 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:28:57 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:29:07 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:29:17 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:29:27 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:29:37 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:29:47 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:29:57 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:30:07 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:30:17 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:30:27 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:30:37 AM IST>     
<22 Nov, 2013 8:30:42 AM IST>

There are 1 nested errors:

weblogic.management.ManagementException: Unable to obtain lock on C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\tmp\DefaultServer.lok. Server may already be running
    at weblogic.management.internal.ServerLocks.getServerLock(ServerLocks.java:206)
    at weblogic.management.internal.ServerLocks.getServerLock(ServerLocks.java:67)
    at weblogic.management.internal.DomainDirectoryService.start(DomainDirectoryService.java:74)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startService(ServerServicesManager.java:461)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.ServerServicesManager.startInStandbyState(ServerServicesManager.java:166)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.initializeStandby(T3Srvr.java:881)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.startup(T3Srvr.java:568)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:469)
    at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:71)

> <22 Nov, 2013 8:30:42 AM IST>     
>   <22 Nov, 2013 8:30:42 AM IST>     
>   <22 Nov, 2013 8:30:42 AM IST>     
>   Process exited.

Answer (score 0):

The quick way to solve this would be to exit JDeveloper and remove the directory:
C:\Users\Dipti\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.1.6.38.61.92\DefaultDomain\
Then restart JDeveloper and run your project again.

Or you can invoke the weblogic console :7101/console and release the lock that you'll see there.